# Cumulative View of Booleans

Tags: python, pandas, boolean

If I have a series that is `[False, False, True, False, True, False]`

I would like to return a cumulative view of `[False, False, True, True, True, True]`

Right now I tend to use `cumsum` and then follow up with a `np.where(series > 0, True, False)`.

But I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cummax.html):

```
pd.Series([False, False, True, False, True, False]).cummax()
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
5     True
dtype: bool
```